# Best way to store Local Storage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I've made a start to a to do list. I've got it adding an item when you submit an item.

I want to now add local storage when you refresh the page so the items are saved in the browser.

I obviously need to save all the times when the page is refreshed but because my items only update on click I'm not sure how to grab that function data outside the function and save the items.

Any ideas?

Cheers

JS Fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/x1bj8mfp/

```
// When submit item
var submit = document.getElementById('form');
submit.addEventListener('submit', addItem);

var items = [];

var itemValues = document.getElementById('items');
var listContainer = document.createElement('ul');
itemValues.appendChild(listContainer);

// Add item
function addItem(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var item = this.querySelector('[name=item]');
    var itemValue = item.value;
    items.push(itemValue);
    item.value = '';

    // Output items
    var listItems = document.createElement('li');
    listItems.innerHTML = itemValue;
    listContainer.appendChild(listItems);
}
```

Comment: Why can't you just save the data every time it changes?

Comment: But the array that stores the items isn't inside the function, is it? And even if it were, why is that keeping you from just saving it to localStorage?

Comment: checkout this package https://github.com/pamelafox/lscache its great for local storage

Comment: Could you guys give an example please?

Comment: Example of what? Are you asking how to save the data to localstorage or what?

Comment: Do you want the page to refresh and submit to server? If not, add a preventDefault to stop the submit or use a type=button

Comment: No I'm asking how in this example the best way to save local storage on page refresh. If I do local storage inside the function then it will only save on click.

Comment: How else can the todo list change? The point is that if you save to localstorage when you add, edit or remove the items, then the localstorage is always in sync with the data so you don't have to save on page refresh, which is always unreliable.

Comment: So are you saying there's no solution to saving the data on page refresh? Isn't that the whole point of local storage?

Comment: No, I'm saying that saving on page refresh is not the best solution to the problem. And no, it's not the whole point of localstorage.

Comment: What is the best solution to the problem?

Comment: I have already said it two times. Save the data to localstorage every time it changes.

Comment: _"So are you saying there's no solution to saving the data on page refresh? Isn't that the whole point of local storage? "_ No, not at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write the whole array to local storage whenever you add an item:

```
localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(items));
```

Then on page load you would read from local storage the array and assign it back to your variable, or set it to `[]` (like now), if nothing is in local storage, and then display these items:

```
var items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items')) || [];
items.forEach(function (itemValue) {
  var listItems = document.createElement('li');
  listItems.textContent = itemValue;
  listContainer.appendChild(listItems);
});
```

This updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x1bj8mfp/1/) has that code included.

Of course, you will need some function to delete items as well, otherwise you can only grow your list.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a full solution for you. Note that the code snippet won't work here, due to the cors and sandbox. Just paste it into your code editor.

```js
var submit = document.getElementById('form');
submit.addEventListener('submit', addItem);

var items = [];

var itemValues = document.getElementById('items');
var listContainer = document.createElement('ul');
itemValues.appendChild(listContainer);


//retrieve data after reload
window.onload = function() {
  if (localStorage.userData != undefined) {
    var userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData'));
    for (var i = 0; i < userData.length; i++) {
      var listItems = document.createElement('li');
      listItems.innerHTML = userData[i];
      listContainer.appendChild(listItems);
      items = userData;
    }
  }
}


// Add item
function addItem(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var item = this.querySelector('[name=item]');
  var itemValue = item.value;
  items.push(itemValue);
  item.value = '';

  // Output items
  var listItems = document.createElement('li');
  listItems.innerHTML = itemValue;
  listContainer.appendChild(listItems);
  localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(items));

}
```

```html
<main>
  <form id="form">
    <input class="form-input" type="text" name="item" placeholder="Add item">
    <input class="btn btn-block" type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
  <div id="items"></div>
  <div id="completed"></div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here some helpful small example for local storage

```js
function save() {
  var fieldvalue = document.getElementById('save').value;
  localStorage.setItem('text', fieldvalue);
}

function load() {
  var storedvalue = localStorage.getItem('textfield');
  if (storedvalue) {
    document.getElementById('textfield').value = storedvalue;
  }
}

function remove() {
  document.getElementById('textfield').value = '';
  localStorage.removeItem('textarea');
}
```

```html
<body onload="load()">
  <input type="textarea" id="textfield">
  <input type="button" value="Save" id="save" onclick="save()">
  <input type="button" value="remove" id="remove" onclick="clr()">
</body>
<!--save& run this in local to see local storage-->
```